# ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist ORACLE 10g XE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, oracle10g, oracle-xe

[image]

Dont know what went wrong.
It worked perfectly first time untill i restarted my Machine.

Comment: Is the database configured to start up automatically; or did you start it manually after your reboot? Or are you trying to connect as sys to start it up - in which case you forgot the `as sysdba` part?

Comment: Also, [please don't use images when you can copy-and-paste text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @AlexPoole - this usually happens when people have just installed Oracle on Ubuntu (and perhaps other unsupported flavors of Linux). The database is started at the end of the installation process, and one can work in it - until they restart the OS, at which point the db does not restart automatically. To be entirely honest, I forgot to do what I put in my Answer below when I installed Oracle on Ubuntu a while back (luckily I remembered there was a step I had skipped... which is what I put in the Answer).

Comment: @mathguy - that's what I figured (and answered on that assumption), though who's still installing 10g? *8-) I think it hasn't restarted automatically; and the attempt to connect as `sys` to do it manually isn't quite right.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your database didn't start automatically after your machine rebooted, and you're trying to connect as `SYS` in order to start it. You're currently trying to connect without specifying the `SYSDBA` role.

```
$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Feb 16 16:04:26 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> connect sys/12345
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
SVR4 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

With the role specified it connects to the idle instance:

```
SQL> connect sys/12345 as sysdba
Connected to an idle instance.
SQL>
```

You can then issue the `startup` command.

You can also connect straight from the command line:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Feb 16 16:07:47 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL>
```

The password you supply for `SYS` can be anything, as it relies on OS authentication anyway. You have to supply the role though. And be logged in to the OS as a user in the right group, of course, and have `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_SID` set correctly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Alex's explanation, in particular the bit about the database not restarting automatically when you restarted your machine:

Navigate to `/etc/oratab` and edit it **as root**.

Find the line

```
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1:N
```

Change the `N` at the very end to `Y`.

This will make the database start up whenever you restart your machine, so you won't have this trouble again.

Comment: Is `rc.oracle` or `init.d/oracle` (or whatever the Ubuntu equivalent is) created automatically to run `dbstart`, even if the startup flag in `oratab` is set to Y? If not the OP would need to do that step too. (And then reboot again, if they don't want to start the DB manually this time!)

Comment: @AlexPoole - that depends 100% on whose "guide" or "instructions" the OP followed to install Oracle on Ubuntu. When I installed 12.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 (just to learn how to do it - I run 12.1 on my Windows laptop most of the time) I followed excellent instructions available at https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/technical-articles/oracle/install-oracle-12c-on-ubuntu-16-04/ - the guy had a script that created almost everything that was needed, but it still requires setting the restart flag manually.

Comment: So it's still something the OP *might* need to go back and do, but fair enough, just setting the flag might be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID should fix.

```
ORACLE_HOME=\<your path>\oracle\product\10.2.0\server
ORACLE_SID=xe
```

Obviusly you have to configure database to startup automatically.

To do so you need to set flag Y to youre instance in `/etc/oratab`
and create appropriate `/etc/init.d/dbora`

Comment: If `ORACLE_HOME` wasn't set or was wrong then SQL\*Plus wouldn't start and would say something like 'Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found'. If `ORACLE_SID` wasn't set you'd get a TNS error. You could get the OP's error if the SID was wrong, though. I think it's more likely the DB just isn't running after the reboot.

Comment: If this was the reason, the OP wouldn't be able to start sessions, terminate them, and start new ones. As he/she stated, this problem came up after restarting the computer. Almost surely due to the database not starting up automatically on restart.

Answer (score 0):

As "chkconfig" doesnt work now.
I tried using sysv-rc-conf but the command not found:
then,
i tried apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
but then shows
E: Unable to locate package sysv-rc-conf

{
i was trying to config : " /etc/init.d/dbora " file to let my database to autostart.
}

Comment: http://www.uni.edu/~prefect/devel/chkconfig/index.shtml

Got that chkconfig package from the above link.
extract the file and paste it into /etc/bin change some of the permission(described in README section)

Answer (score 0):

This set of errors can occur when you don't have properly set ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME variables.

Note, the ORACLE_HOME variable is supposed not to end with a slash char. So, even though it seems everything is configured fine, trailing slash in the ORACLE_HOME value will lead to the issue too:

```
# wrong:
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/11gR2/

# correct:
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/11gR2
```